# Usage of split, rstrip, append in lists

Tags: list, sorting, split, append

This weeks assignment is a question about lists and i couldn't get rid of the list symbols.

Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.split()
    lst.append(line)
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: Get rid of [] by using join '  '.join(lst). Also if you want check duplicates, you'd better use a set rather than using a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments a `set` would be better for this but since the assignment is about lists, try something like this:

```
list_of_words = []
with open('romeo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in list_of_words:
                list_of_words.append(word)

sorted_list_of_words = sorted(list_of_words)
print(' '.join(sorted_list_of_words))
```

**Output:**

```
Arise But It Juliet Who already and breaks east envious fair grief is kill light moon pale sick soft sun the through what window with yonder
```

**Alternative solution that asks for filename from user, uses continue and is compatible with python 2.x:**

```
fname = raw_input('Enter file: ')

wordlist = list()
for line in open(fname, 'r'):
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in wordlist: continue
        wordlist.append(word)

wordlist.sort()
print ' '.join(wordlist)
```

Output:

```
Enter file: romeo.txt
Arise But It Juliet Who already and breaks east envious fair grief is kill light moon pale sick soft sun the through what window with yonder
```